# Can pass custom object in request and receive response as "*/*" (Mediatype.ALL_VALUE) in post

Tags: spring-boot, post, resttemplate

I'm trying to trigger restApi using restTemplate.Request accepts the json(for which I've created a custom object) and sends the response as "*/*" mediaType.

Expected Request:

```
{
"domainObject" :{
    "amount" : "1230798F",
    "business" : "n/a",
    "productGroup" : "n/a",
    "productType" : "n/a",
    "balanceType" : "n/a", 
    "balanceSubType" : "n/a"       
},
   "uniqueId" : "test1",
    "userId" : "user1"
}
```

My DTOs:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
class DomainObject(){
   private Float amount;
   private String business;
   private String productGroup;
   private String productType;
   private String balanceType;
   private String balanceSubType;

}

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
class PayloadObject(){

   @Autowired
   private DomainObject domainObject;

   private String uniqueId;
   private String userId;
}

public void testRestTemplate(){
PayloadObject obj = new PayloadObject(domainObject, "test-1", "abc");
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://dev-test";

}
```

Can you please guide me how can I use restTemplate in this scenario, any help would be much appreciated.

Edit1 : When I'm trying to use below code:

```
//make the object
NewObject obj = new NewObject();
obj.setStuff("stuff");

//set your headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

//set your entity to send
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(obj,headers);

// send it!
ResponseEntity<String> out = restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, entity
    , String.class);`
```

It throws an error saying "No HttpMessageConverter for Object and content type "application/json"

Edit2: I tried to add messageConverter as below:

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverter = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
converter.setSupportMediaType(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
msgConverter.add(converter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverter);
```

But still it gives the same error.
I wonder if I need to write custom message converter? Can someone please help me out understand if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

The the retune type should be PayloadObject instead String type.

```
ResponseEntity<PayloadObject> out = restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, entity
, PayloadObject.class);
```